# Window Function- Dense_Rank and Row_Number difference

Tags: sql, presto

If I use a dense_rank window function below that works in giving me my output which is the transaction refunded at dates in ascending order and assigns it 1 as rank:

```
select p.billing_cycle_in_months, avg(t.days)
from (
    select *, 
        datediff(day,transaction_settled_at, transaction_refunded_at) as days,
        dense_rank() over (partition by signup_id order by transaction_settled_at asc) as rank
    from transactions
) t
join signups s on s.signup_id = t.signup_id
join plans p on p.id = s.plan_id
where datediff(year,s.started_at, current_date) > 1 and t.rank = 1
group by p.billing_cycle_in_months
```

Would I essentially get same result as using row_number window function ranked over same date (transaction_settled_at asc) column?

Basically grouped by billing cycle I want to rank the earliest day as 1, just wanted to clairfy that in this case row_number would give me same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, the difference between using [`dense_rank()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#dense_rank) and [`row_number()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) is that the former allows top ties, while the latter does not.

So if two (or more) records have the same, earliest, `transaction_settled_at` for a given `signup_id`, then condition `dense_rank() ... = 1` will keep them both, while `row_number()` will select an undefined record out of the two.

If there no risk of ties, both functions will in your context produce the same resulting dataset.

To reduce the possibility of ties, you can also add additional sorting criterias to the `order by` clause of the window function:

```
dense_rank() over (
    partition by signup_id 
    order by transaction_settled_at, some_other_column desc, some_more_column
)
```

Comment: By row_number() keeping an undefined record out of the two you mean grabbing just one of the ties correct?

Also how can you have additional criteria to order by clause to reduce ties? Thanks @GMG

Comment: Thanks for (2) how would the other column desc or asc affect the same row that would be ranked 1? They would have the same attributes in all columns

Comment: I cannot tell since I can't see your data. But the idea is to have columns thatn can be used to break the ties (ie they do not have the same values for all duplicate rows). If both records are perfect duplicates (ie all columns are the same), then you cannot disambiguate them.